# SSRS parameter filtering out union part of the query

Tags: t-sql, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

In my SSRS Report, I have a column named 'Producer Name' and a parameter field call 'ProducerName'. It's currently returning all my producer name rows but in my sql query I union another row call 'Producer Name' + 'Totals'. My SSRS report won't return any of the producer name that has 'total' added on. How do I go about fixing this?

What its currently returning:

```
Producer Name       Count
    Prod A            15
    Prod A             6
    Prod A             2
    Prod B             4
```

What it's suppose to return:

```
    Producer Name         count
        Prod A             15
        Prod A              6
        Prod A              2
        Prod A Totals      23
        Prod B              4
        Prod B Totals       4
```

I'm thinking it's because my ProducerName parameter won't recognize the word "totals" that I added onto the rows when I union the two statement. any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution would be to remove the `UNION` from the query entirely and just handle the `Producer Name` grouping and group totals at the report level.

What you're describing is basic SSRS functionality, so as you may as well leverage the functionality provided by the tool.